# Hide Splash Screen in Ionic Capacitor React

Tags: reactjs, ionic4, splash-screen, capacitor

How can we disable the splash screen on an Ionic App? I am using Ionic 4, Capacitor and React. I have tried to add this on capacitor.config.json

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is not working at all.

Comment: did you find how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the splash screen using the `SplashScreen` plugin :

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { SplashScreen } = Plugins;

function useSplashHide(){
    useEffect(() => {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }, []);
}
```

You can use it like any hooks :

```
function MyComponent(props){
  useSplashHide()

  return <>....</>
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/splash-screen/)

Comment: @LengLong how exactly did you use it, not able to get it to work

Comment: @kkakroo I have edited the answer to show you how to use it, it is a normal hook so you can use it like any hooks.

Comment: I tried this in Login.tsx(which is my first loaded component) and also in App.tsx. Also tried calling it as a component. That didn't work too.

Answer (score -1):

capcitor version v2

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/splash-screen

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { SplashScreen } = Plugins;
```

1.call hide()

```
// Hide the splash (you should do this on app launch)
SplashScreen.hide();<------------------------call hide function
```

2.or set showduration  to 0

```
// Show the splash for two seconds and then auto hide:
SplashScreen.show({
  showDuration: 0,<------------------------set 0 duration to hide
  autoHide: true,
});
```

Verion v3

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen

Answer (score -3):

You can just add below line in `config.xml`

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I know that works if you use Cordova, but I'm currently using Capacitor which doesn't have config.xml